# Cleaning up duplicate entries in a Wix installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I need some advice about how to clean up an old Wix project that hasn't been managed very well. One problem is that the project currently has multiple entries for the same files, going to the same location. For example, several .wxs files in the project will define a new component for foo.exe, each using a different GUID and each sending this file to the same DirectoryRef. This hasn't yet created any issues, but now I want to use patches (MSPs) in our product and this sort of thing messes with their operation.

I'm wondering about the best way to resolve this without breaking upgrades (since all previous installers have gone out like this). If I simply remove all the duplicate components, we get undefined behavior during an upgrade. I think what's happening is that removing one or more duplicate entries will cause the installer to generate delete operations for that file. Even if the remaining entry for the file is a new version, there is no guarantee in the order of operations during the install. So some of these files will first get updated, then one or more delete operations will remove the updated file. Thus at the end of the upgrade several files will be missing. Running a repair immediately afterwards will restore the files, since the installer knows they are supposed to be there.

I imagine one way to resolve this is to do a one off "hack" in our next release, where we copy these files into a secondary location, then run a custom action post install that copies the files from the secondary location into the primary and delete the temporary directory.

Is there a cleaner way this could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

What you are likely going to have to do is use validation to identify all the duplicates and fix them.  Then change your upgrade to be a major upgrade with the earliest possible scheduling.  You may also have to change your install location to a slightly different directory to get around component reference counts breaking.

Once clean you should be able to go back to minor upgrades and start thinking about patching.  An alternative would be "fake" patches.  I've used an MSI that doesn't publish itself as a hotfix method very successfully.  It breaks a lot of rules but can be useful for organizations that don't care about patching rules and just want to make the business happy.